# 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, django

**'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter'**
why?)
I'm trying to create a blog in django, got to the stage of adding comments and categories and got stuck
I get an error.

```
views.py 

    from django.shortcuts import render, 
    get_object_or_404
    from .models import Post, Comment
    from django.views import generic
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from .forms import CommentForm
    def blog_list(request):
    post = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    return render(request,'blog/blog_list.html', {'posts':post})
    def blog_detail(request, slug):
    #return HttpResponse(slug)
    detail_post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    comments = Post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():

            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'blog/blog_detail.html', {'detail_post':detail_post, 'comments':comments, 'new_comment': new_comment, 'comment_form': comment_form})
```

I hope someone helps, also with the problem of adding a category

```
14.comments = Post.comments.filter(active=True) …
```

▶ Local vars

here is my
models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

   

    class Post(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       slug = models.SlugField()
       body = models.TextField()
       date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    first_src = models.CharField('первоисточник', blank=True, max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE )
    thumb = models.ImageField(default='default.png', blank=True)

    # add AND GO TO MIGRATE AND MAKEMIGRATIONS !!!

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:50]+'...'

    """def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.urls import reverse
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"slug": str(self.slug)})"""


    class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

What's wrong?

> I hope someone helps, also with the problem of adding a category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to filter on the class (`Post`), but want to filter on the specific model (`detail_post`):

```py
    comments = detail_post.comments.filter(active=True)
```